# Spit PNG into multiple images on Ubuntu with imagemagick

Tags: ocr, imagemagick-convert

This image contains 30 blocks of user data. I plan to extract these 30 blocks as PNG files and then run tesseract-ocr to extract text from them. Can someone tell me how I can use imagemagick to get those 30 PNG files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me in ImageMagick. I first crop to the array of boxes. Then I crop a set of 3x10 equal sized boxes.

```
convert image.png -crop 1125x1500+43+99 +repage -crop 3x10@ +repage result_%02d.png
```

See 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_repage
http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick will work well. In their [document](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop) , there are eamxamples that you can use

```
convert rose: -crop 40x30+10+10  crop.gif
# from point (40, 30) take a (width=10, height=10) frame and save into crop.gif
```

In your case, you have to find correct coordinate and size, then you can do it automatically. Just run and try, it will not consume too much time.

Hope that help